# Using Apache POI lib I want to get date value from a cell that is FORMULA type - function doesn't read the date as desired

Tags: java, excel, kotlin, excel-formula, apache-poi

as the title says - currently I have a function that works well
excep when...

Following is the cell I want to get data from

="text" & TEXT(TODAY();"RRRR-MM-DD") & "text"

apparently the format between two ampersands is the issue.

```
.
.
row = sheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow())
cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol().toInt(), Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK)
var dataFormatter = DataFormatter()

//casting this will return everything correctly as a string however the date is in unix timestamp
//of 01/01/1970 - returned value is 45160.0
if(cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.FORMULA)
{
      return dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell, evalautor)
}
.
.
```

The most success I've had with this was casting the following

```
if(cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.FORMULA)
{
      return cell.richStringCellValue.getString()
}
```

the code above works except it does NOT return the correct date of TODAY(). Instead this returns the date of when the excel file was last saved.
Calling any kind of cell evaluation has not worked so far and I am running out of ideas.
If I open the file and manually save it before running the script, this will work and return the correct value of posting this post today => 2023-08-08.

Comment: Have you tried evaluator.evaluate(cell) and then work with the resulting CellValue to format it?

Comment: @CjY Hello, yes I have. The result is the same. Adding evaluator.evaluate(cell) above return cell.richStringCellValue.getString() will return the same output as if the evaluator.evaluate(cell) was not even present. The date is not today, rather currently 2023-08-03.

Comment: The formula looks incorrect. Do you want to fix it above?

Comment: Should your formula be `="text" & TEXT(TODAY(), "YYYY-MM-DD") & "text"` ?

Comment: I am able to get the expected value with the formula fixed.

Comment: I assume this has something to do with the country where I am in? The excel file is a template and is not created by me. Perhaps there is a possibility to change this format to YYYY-MM-DD. I will look into it, Thanks.

Comment: The semicolon in the formula seems to be an error, but the "RRRR" may be a locale thing.

Comment: This seems to have worked! Indeed, the locale was the problem. For some time now, my pc has been set to my native locale even though I prefer to have it set to English(UK).

I changed everything to UK and rebooted the pc. After that, the formulas have automatically adjusted to YYYY-MM-DD format and the semicolon changed to a comma! Thanks everyone for their help.